# log4j not logging when "Task" is in the log message?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons-logging

It seems like Log4j is not logging any message containing "Task" using a ConsoleAppender.

```
public class Main
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Log log = LogFactory.getLog("Main");
        log.info("'task' is logged, but");
        log.info("'Task' is not logged ?!");

        // wait for logging to finish
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, CA

log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c.%M - %m%n
```

I use commons-logging 1.2, log4j 1.2.17, openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14

Is this a bug? A FileAppender works normally. I can also System.out.println("Task") and see it on the console, so it is not my IDE filtering anything.

I would be happy if someone can try this and verify it, because I am super confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my IntelliJ IDEA plugin *Grep Console* was filtering lines with `.*Task.*` due to import of the company configuration.
In IntelliJ, go to Settings > Other Settings > Grep Console > Input filtering. Check if there is any unexpected.

Comment: I still don't know why `System.out.println("Task")` was printing to the console though. But it does not matter anymore.